# JQuery multiple class selectors fails in IE6

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-6

I make use of class selectors in JQuery and this works fine but in IE6 this fails as it does not apply the width I would like.

```
    $('.ui-state-default .ui-jqgrid-hdiv').css('width', width);
```

If I try it one class it works?? But I need to apply that width to a div that has both those classes.

Thanks all for any help.

### Update

```
$onselect = <<<loadComplete
function go_size(){

        var width = document.documentElement.clientWidth - 45;
        $('#gbox_grid').css('width', width);
        $('#gview_grid').css('width', width);
        $('#pager').css('width', width);
        $('.ui-state-default .ui-jqgrid-hdiv').css('width', width);
        $('.ui-jqgrid-bdiv').css('width', width)

}
loadComplete;
```

Comment: It's possible that the *selector* is working just fine, but the "width" attribute is not being obeyed. The selection engine is mostly independent of the browsers, but there's nothing jQuery can do to fix the IE 6 layout engine.

Comment: The width element seems to work with other div elements selected by id and one css selector. See my JS function. It seems the width attribute is being obeyed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the space between the class names. With your posted selector, you search for a *child* element `.ui-jqgrid-hdiv` inside a parent `.ui-state-default`.

Look [here (W3C)](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) and [here (jQuery)](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for how to write selectors.

Also, look, if the class attribute spans multiple lines in the HTML source. IE 6 can't handle that correctly.

Comment: Fantastic! I just removed the space and it worked. I didn't realise it worked like that?! Thank you Boldewyn!

Comment: @Abs: I suggest you to read the jQuery docs about selectors. You can do amazing things with selectors *even* (almost) *completely without* harming elements with class names or IDs.

Comment: I will have a read of those two links since I really need to no more about selectors as I will be doing quite a fair bit of work with JQuery.